# Pass PHP array integer to JavaScript function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i am using **PHP Codeigniter** and trying to **pass array** from *Controller* to *JavaScript* function using **onClick()** but could not find any solution.

Here is my code in controller:

```
function get_class_students_mass_pdf($class_id) {

        $students = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array(
            'class_id' => $class_id, 'year' => $this->db->get_where('settings', array('type' => 'running_year'))->row()->description
        ))->result_array();
        
        $invoiceid = array();
        foreach ($students as $row) {
            $invoice_id =  $this->db->get_where('invoice', array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->invoice_id;

                $invoiceid[] = $invoice_id;
        
            }

            $invoiceid = json_encode($invoiceid);
    
        echo '<br><br><button style="margin-left: 36px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="invoice_view_modal('.$invoiceid.')"> ' . get_phrase('generate_pdf') . ' </button>';
    }
```

My JavaScript Function in View:

```
    function invoice_view_modal(invoiceid) {
          showAjaxModal('<?php echo site_url('modal/popup/modal_view_mass_invoice/');? 
          >' + invoiceid);
     }
```

**$invoiceid** is my array that I am trying to **access** in my JavaScript Function using **onClick()** method.How do I access it?

Comment: `$invoiceid is my array` - what does that mean? After having called `json_encode`, that is no longer an array. Did you try to dump it to inspect the content?

Comment: It will be helpful if you describe what you want to achieve

Comment: How many invoice IDs are you expecting your SQL query to output? If it's just one, then why are you putting it into an array?

Comment: Also why are you echoing direct from a PHP function - pretty sure that's not how codeigniter is supposed to work.

Comment: @ADyson there will always be multiple invoice IDs

Comment: Well that contradicts with your `invoice_view_modal` which appears to expect a single invoice ID. So how do you propse to square that circle? Are you actually supposed to be generating a separate `<button>` for each invoice ID in the array, rather than a single one?

Comment: @RioSant i want to pase the $invoiceID array to the JavaScript function "invoice_view_modal()" when i click on the "generate_pdf" button.

Comment: @ADyson No i am performing my task with single button for all invoice IDs that is why i want to parse invoice Id array to my JavaScript function. Kindly tell me how do i make my JavaScript function to accept that array.

Comment: Well the JS function will accept it, because it's basically a JSON string, it's just text. Have you looked what's actually being passed into it, using your JS debugger? The problem is likely to come at this point, I would guess: `showAjaxModal('<?php echo site_url('modal/popup/modal_view_mass_invoice/');? 
          >' + invoiceid);` ...this looks like it's trying to form a URL, and put the JSON string directly into the URL...I doubt the server can parse that when it (presumably) makes a request to that URL. What does that server action actually expect to receive?

Comment: Please add all clarification that helps to understand your problem better to the question itself by editing it. "Kindly tell me how do i make my JavaScript function to accept that array" - what do you mean by that? Are you facing any **specific** problem with that, in terms of "the function does not accept that array"?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes Js function is not accepting that array

Comment: What does "not accepting" mean? Is the input to that function even an array, or something else? Keep in mind to add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at student_payment:1:26)** this is the error i am getting in console. And my JS function is in **student_payment** view

Comment: Please share the generated markup, such that others can inspect it. Also, **add all clarification to your question by editing it**

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in my project and after debugging i came to know that javaScript function not accepting the **special characters** in the array like **","**. so i simply use ***htmlspecialchars()*** and it works for mine.
Try this,

```
$invoiceid = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($invoiceid));
```